# Comma should come in italic font inside equations

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, italic

My tags are as follow:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}

Test \quad $a,b$\quad \textit{a, b}\quad a, b


\end{document}
```

In this, I need to get the comma character to be in italic font within both inline and display equations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why should it? I see no reason.

Comment: @egreg This requirement is raised by one of a Professor...

Comment: You deserve my sympathy. ;-)

Comment: @MadyYuvi you are allowed to say no, and point to more or less any published math work, which does not do that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, will say the same and get back to you...

Comment: Honestly, would any reasonable person even notice, let alone care about, the difference?

Comment: @DavidRicherby are you saying all professors are reasonable?

Comment: @ChrisH You may very well think this professor is completely unreasonable. I couldn’t possibly comment.

Comment: I think the professor is making the (wrong) assumption that math is typeset in italics. In fact, math is a mix of numbers, symbols, variables, operators, functions, etc. Standard convention is that variables and the like are indeed typeset in italics. However, it is also standard to typeset special functions like sin or exp in upright letters. Having then punctuation upright seems perfectly reasonable, considering there is a mix of upright and italics. So (*a*, *b*) is standard (and reasonable), whereas *(* sin *x, b)* (italic punctuation) is certainly not standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redeclare the comma in math mode.

### With `newtx` (to be preferred over `txfonts`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % no txfonts, please

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{italic}{\tx@enc}{\rmdefaultB}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{italic}{bold}{\tx@enc}{\rmdefaultB}{\bold@wt}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{italic}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{italic}{`,}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test \quad $a,b$\quad \textit{a, b}\quad a, b

\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `txfonts`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\DeclareSymbolFont{italic}{OT1}{txr}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{italic}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{italic}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{italic}{`,}

\begin{document}

Test \quad $a,b$\quad \textit{a, b}\quad a, b

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Some explanations

The `newtxmath` package defines a math alphabet

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{\tx@enc}{\rmdefaultB}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{\tx@enc}{\rmdefaultB}{\bold@wt}{it}
```

but we want to borrow the comma from this font as a math symbol. So instead we declare a symbol font with the same parameters (encoding, family, weight and shape) and redeclare `\mathit` with `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`. Then the declaration of the comma is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `\textit{}` around a comma will make the comma character italic in math mode. So:

```
$a\textit{,}b$
```

Comment: thanks for your advise, it is any way to achieve this without doing the manual thing?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could make a custom command for this but then you would still have to replace your commas by that custom command. At that point you would probably just save time by typing the comma and pressing `Ctrl+I` in your editor.

Comment: @Flexo013 You don't know what editor I'm using, so you don't know what `ctrl+I` will do...

Comment: @DavidRicherby that is correct. You can simply find the equivalent shortcut for your editor of choice. I was merely providing a commonly used shortcut for italicizing text.